# Numbered List in Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am using Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll to dynamically build a Word document in C#.

Does anyone have a code example to create a a numbered list?

Comment: I don't have an example to hand, but one really easy way to find this sort of thing is to record a macro and then look at the recorded macro's code. There's usually a lot of extraneous stuff you don't need, but the meat of it is usually pretty apparent and points you in the right direction...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this... it assumes you have a reference to Word10 (you can use other versions, you'll have to change the constants). Don't forget the `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;`

```
// setup
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
Document doc = app.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, 
    ref missing, ref missing);
app.Visible = true;

// whatever is selected will be turned into a numbered list.
object n = 1;
ListTemplate template = 
    app.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery].ListTemplates.get_Item(ref n);
ListLevel level = template.ListLevels[1];
level.NumberFormat = "%1.";
level.TrailingCharacter = WdTrailingCharacter.wdTrailingTab;
level.NumberStyle = WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic;
level.NumberPosition = app.InchesToPoints(0.25f);
level.Alignment = WdListLevelAlignment.wdListLevelAlignLeft;
level.TextPosition = app.InchesToPoints(0.5f);
level.TabPosition = (float)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.ResetOnHigher = 0;
level.StartAt = 1;

level.Font.Bold = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Italic = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.StrikeThrough = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Subscript = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Superscript = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Shadow = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Outline = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Emboss = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Engrave = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.AllCaps = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Hidden = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
level.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorAutomatic;
level.Font.Size = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;
level.Font.Animation = WdAnimation.wdAnimationNone;
level.Font.DoubleStrikeThrough = (int)WdConstants.wdUndefined;

level.LinkedStyle = "";

template.Name = "";
object bContinuePrevList = false;
object applyTo = WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList;
object defBehavior = WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior;

app.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(
    template, ref bContinuePrevList, 
    ref applyTo, ref defBehavior, ref missing);
```

edit: formatting.