# C# Word Add-in Creating Ordered Lists with VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto

I am new to VSTO development, so please bear with me! I am working on an add-in to Word which takes the elements from a String[] and types them in an ordered list (1., 2., 3., etc.). However, I am having great difficulty in doing this. Could someone please explain how to insert an ordered list into a Word Doc using VSTO for C#?

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Comment: Answered in Stack Overflow already.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939995/numbered-list-in-microsoft-word

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! If you create an answer mentioning that post, I'll accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939995/numbered-list-in-microsoft-word).

You have to retreive a [ListTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.listtemplate) from [ListGalleries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.listgalleries) and then set styles for the [ListLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.listlevel)

Good example is given in the other post.